# How to push and pop from a stack in Assembly mips?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I want to create push and pop methods in mips assembly. Here's the code in java:

```
static int pop ()
{
    if (i == 0) {
        System.out.println ("Invalid Postfix");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    i--;
    return (p[i]);
}
```

and

```
static void push (int result)
{
    if (i == MAX) {
        System.out.println ("Too many tokens");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    p[i] = result;
    i++;
}
```

So far, I've created the push method:

```
push:
    beq $s1, $s0, error_overflow
    sw $t2 , stack($t7)          # p[i] = result
    addi $t7, $t7, 4             # go to space for next int
    addi $s1, $s1, 1             # i++

    jr $ra
```

However I don't know how to translate the `return (p[i])` statement in assembly. Are return values stored in `$v0`? Will I have to move the contents of `$v0` to another registry? Any google searches on the subject have only confused me. Any help?

If my code in mips is confusing here's a cheat sheet:

```
$s0 = MAX
$s1 = stack pointer
$t7 = where I will store the numbers
$t2 = the number(result) that will be stored.
```

Comment: Rather than use `stack($t7)`, I'd use the register designated as the stack pointer (i.e. `$sp` aka `$r29`).  If `$sp` needs to be set up, do `la $sp,stack_high` at start.  Then, use `sw $whatever,0($sp)`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the [MIPS ABI](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/mipsabi32.pdf) as reference:

> Are return values stored in $v0?

Yes.

> Will I have to move the contents of $v0 to another registry?

No, that's not necessary. $vX registers are like the $tX registers, you don't need to back them up. It's the caller not the callee that needs to take care of backing up those registers if it cares about them.

PS: note that you can in fact use any other register or even memory for the return value if you want.

Comment: Thanks @m0skit0 ! Does that mean my code will look something like this?

beq $s1, $zero, error_underflow
lw $v0, stack($t7)
addi  $t7, $t7, -4
addi $s1, $s1, -1 # i--